# Web Application Compatible with IE6 alone, How to run it on IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, iis, asp.net

I have a custom ASP.NET web application which runs fine on IE6 without any issues. However, if I launch it on IE7/IE8, it complains of compatibility issues and all of my text is all overlapped.

A colleague of mine ( Microsoft Link is as here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968499 )sent these instructions.

```
 Click Start, click Run, type inetmgr.exe in the Open box, and then click OK. 

 Expand the server that you want, and then expand Web Sites. 

 Right-click the Web site, the folder, or the virtual directory that you want, and then click Properties. 

 On the HTTP Headers tab, click Add under Custom HTTP headers. 

 In the Custom header name box, type X-UA-Compatible. 

 In the Custom header valuebox, type IE=EmulateIE7. 

 Click OK two times
```

Now, he told that this is what needs to be done for making applications compatible with IE7 to run when I run an IE8 browser and just changing IE=EmulateIE7 to IE=EmulateIE6 should make the application compatible with IE6 to work on IE7 as well (I had my apprehensions, because I know that IE8 comes with a button which says compatible with IE6, but I have never seen a similar button in IE7).

Needless to say, it did not work!

Any thoughts on why it won't work this way for IE6?

Comment: Because IE6 is an abomination and should be destroyed.

Comment: @Phoshi: I know this is wrong and doesn't help anyone, but I wanna upvote you so many times.

Comment: This is the 'which button do I press to make it work' attitude so prevalent today. The problem here, as Phoshi said, is that IE6 is broken. A website which works well with IE6 is effectively broken too, and shouldn't be exected to work properly with an improved browser.

Comment: Completely agree, howeer, we are not upgrading the web application anytime soon and we definitely need to be on IE7. I know I am asking for both the sun and moon at the same time, but can we get a diamond ring here without an eclipse?

Comment: I doubt it - IE8 includes a compatibility mode, *just to try and kill off IE6*, but IE7 had no such thing. I'm afraid it's either IE6, or IE8. (Please don't use IE6 :()

Comment: To be blunt, if you wrote it, fix it. If someone else wrote it, tell them to fix it for compatibility with IE7, or ask them to buy you another Windows licence, so that you can run their weird legacy software in a VM with IE6.

Comment: @njd - Thanks for the blunt response. Unfortunately, we are the service provider now (we inherited this junk), so we are fixing it. I guess, a more appropriate decision would be a job change :-)

Answer (score 1):

IE 7, 8, Firefox, Chrome, are much more standard compliant.  But if the app can only run on IE 6 and your machine already has IE 7 installed, then you can try running a Virtual Machine with a disk image with IE 6.

You can google VPC 2007 for Microsoft's Virtual PC 2007, and google vhd for the disk images.

VPC 2007 is officially for XP but the general consensus is it is also good for Vista.

VirtualBox is also a good alternative as a virtual pc.  If you use Win 7, you can google virtual pc for the new info on the new Windows Virtual PC.

Comment: No, it is for my organization as a whole. So, having VPC is not an option. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You're problably looking at some stylesheet issues rather than anything in the code behind of the application. The rendering of pages in IE6 is much different than IE7 or 8. I've run into the same issues on occassion and usually it's just a simple tweek of a defind style.

You can use the **IE Developer Toolbar** (which works in both IE7 and comes standard in 8) to see the layout of divs tables and etc along with the associated styles. Find the offending markup, tweek it in both browsers until you can get a consistant rendering across the diffrent browsers.

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Comment: Link to IE developer toolbar: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Comment: Toolbar also works in IE6.

Comment: You are correct. It's been such a long time since I've used 6 I totally forgot about having had it installed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is no "EmulateIE6".  The possible vaules are listed in [HTTP-EQUIV Attribute | httpEquiv Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876(VS.85).aspx).

I would try setting it to "IE=5" and see if that helps.

And absolutely imperative that you update the browsers to something modern.